# jquery slide out tab behind flash

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, slide

on this site the slide out tab on the right slides behind the flash.
any ideas on how to get it to slide over it?

Comment: On which site? The question seems pretty vague can you add some specifics?

Answer (score 1):

try this http://www.chromicdesign.com/2009/03/floating-div-above-embedded-flash-object.html

Comment: Works with swfObject too:

var flashvars = {};

var params = {};
params.menu = “false”;
params.quality = “best”;
params.scale = “showall”;
params.allowfullscreen = true;
params.wmode = “opaque”; //z-index below dropdowns

var attributes = {};
attributes.id = attributes.name = “MyAwesomeFlashFile”;

swfobject.embedSWF(“Flash/sweetness.swf”, “MyAwesomeFlashFile”, “640″, “300″, “9.0.0″, “expressInstall.swf”, flashvars, params, attributes);